# Safety Capacitors; Is it OK to fit an X1 in place of an X2?

Tags: rf, safety, emi-filtering, alternatives, x-capacitor

I have a PCB which has a 0.010uF X**2** safety capacitor fitted. It seems the exact part is now obsolete.

Would it be acceptable to replace this part with a 0.010uF X**1** safety capacitor?

I believe a capacitors subclass is decided according to its peak/rated and impulse voltages. With an X1s ratings surpassing those of the of X2 and X3.

I know I could probably find another 0.010uF X**2** to replace it.

I also know I have not provided much information about the overall application. Which is because it's ancient and I have limited supporting documentation (typically).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. X1 has higher voltage withstand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X1, X2 and X3 voltage ratings: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/safety-capacitor-class-x-and-class-y-capacitors/). Same info; different source: -

[image]

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.we-online.com/web/de/electronic_components/news_pbs/blog_pbcm/blog_detail-worldofelectronics_109175.php).

> *Would it be acceptable to replace this part with a 0.010uF X1 safety capacitor?*

Regarding voltage ratings, X1 has better specifications.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation Andy, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I also found the following slide provided by KEMET. Might be useful as it references Y capacitors  too...

[image]

Comment: That KEMET slide says "VAC" over the symbol for DC.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes. The 1500 VAC should read 1500 VDC, based on the text just above it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Good spot! I'll adjust the image accordingly.